# Which is right to say: "i went home early last Friday'' or ''i came home early last Friday''?

Tags: word-usage

Which is right to say when you are already home and on phone with someone?

> "I went home early last Friday''

or

> ''I came home early last Friday''

Answer (score 1):

"I went home early" is talking about the time that you left work.

"I came home early" is talking about the time that you arrived at your home.

> I went home early on Friday, and left the office at 4:30. But there was a crash on the motorway and I came home very late, after 8pm.

Answer (score 0):

You can say either.  They both convey exactly the same meaning, but are expressed from a different point of view (one from the point of view of being at home, and the other from the point of view of not being at home).